# matrix which takes as value 1 if an edge exist between 2 nodes and 0 otherwise from an adjacency dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, adjacency-matrix, edges

I have an adjacency dictionary like this:

```
{1: {8, 2}, 2: {3}, 5: {9, 7}, 7: {8}, 3: {8, 4}, 4: {5}, 8: {9}, 9: {7}}
```

My code to do it is :

```
list = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 7), (5, 9), (7, 8), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 7), (1, 8), (3, 8)]

dic = {}
for x, y in list:
    dic.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
return dic
```

And I want to produce a matrix which takes as value 1 if an edge exist between 2 nodes and 0 otherwise. Here an example of what I want :

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

This is what I want with my adjacency dictionary.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution

```
import numpy as np
dic = {1: {8, 2}, 2: {3}, 5: {9, 7}, 7: {8}, 3: {8, 4}, 4: {5}, 8: {9}, 9: {7}}
arr = np.zeros((9,9))
for k in dic.keys():
    for v in dic[k]:
        arr[k-1][v-1] = 1
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import pprint

lst = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 7), (5, 9), (7, 8), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 7), (1, 8), (3, 8)]

dic = {}
for x, y in lst:
    dic.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)

size = max(dic) + 1
result = [[int(j in dic and i in dic[j]) for i in range(1, size)] for j in range(1, size)]

pprint.pprint(result) # just for pretty printing
```